# sed: finding consecutive *similar* lines -- zip codes

Tags: sed

I have a file with addresses in which some addresses have the city zip line twice.

Example

```
Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
TIMBUKTU, AK 99909
```

I'd like to keep the first, so I thought a sed one-liner such as the following might work:

```
sed -e '$!N' -e "s/\(.* 9[0-9]\{4\}\)\n.* 9[0-9]\{4\}/\1/" processme.txt
```

The weird part is: it works on files with no blank lines --- but not ones with.

???

Thoughts?

Comment: You can dis-regard my answer since it uses `awk`. I didn't see the `sed` only tag.

Comment: Actually, I just need to solve this --- awk is fine. I'm just more familiar with sed. The old 'if all you have is a hammer ...' syndrome.

Comment: Sounds good. :) I made one more change to the answer. Can you please test it against your file.

Comment: Your awk statement doesn't work either.

Comment: I did a test on a sample file. If you can tell me what the issue is then may be I can work it out.

Comment: The problem is my brain and it's *assumptions* regarding the file. :(  The city zip line got duplicated as many as 4 times instead of just twice like I assumed. Your awk statement works beautifully, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still wanted to use `sed`

#### Keep 1st occurrence

```
sed 'N;/9[[:digit:]]\{4\}\n.*9[[:digit:]]\{4\}/{P;d;D};P;D' processme.txt
```

#### Keep 2nd occurrence

```
sed 'N;/9[[:digit:]]\{4\}\n.*9[[:digit:]]\{4\}/D;P;D' processme.txt
```

Also, the use of `[[:digit:]]` over `[0-9]` is preferred as the former works across locales.

Comment: I think he'd like to keep the first address not the last.

Comment: Yes I'd like to keep the first.

Comment: @Bubnoff ok, I updated my answer to accommodate either case.  Note that the only reason my first answer kept the 2nd occurrence was because that is what the answer you accepted does.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm going to check this out against my records and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** to include first match instead of second.

```
awk 'NF{a=$NF; b=$0; getline; if(a~$NF) {print b;next} else {print b; print $0; next}}1' file
```

#### Input File:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
TIMBUKTU, AK 99909

Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
TIMBUKTU, AK 99909
Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
TIMBUKTU, AK 99909

Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
TIMBUKTU, AK 99909
```

#### Output:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NF{a=$NF; b=$0; getline; if(a~$NF) {print b;next} else {print b; 

print $0; next}}1' file
Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909

Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909

Joe Schmoe
4545 RANDOM ADDRESS ST NE
TIMBUKTU AK 99909
```

Comment: But the lines aren't the same, only similar.

Comment: I need to match on zip code. Eventually,I'd like to run it in a shell script against an array of zip codes.

Comment: Yea, I am only matching the last field which is the `zip code` as shown in the conditional `if (a==$NF)`. I modified it to `if(a~$NF)`

Comment: Did you try with the latest version? What issue are you getting. I recently updated the answer to include `NF`.

Comment: My mistake, your awk statement *is* working. Somehow the city zip was duplicated 3 to 4 times. It does work against a doubled line -- Thanks! I think this explains my sed statement's failure as well.

Comment: I think he'd like to keep the first address not the last

Comment: That's a simple fix. In the `if` conditional, instead of printing `$0` we can print `b`.

Comment: @Bubnoff Updated to find the first match instead of second. It was a simple fix. Instead of `print $0` we had to `print b`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed ':a;$!N;/ \(9[0-9]\{4\}\)\n.*\(9[0-9]\{4\}\)/s/\n.*//;ta;P;D' file
```

This handles multilple consecutive *similar* lines.
Or this:

```
sed '/9[0-9]\{4\}/!b;:a;$!{N;/\n\s*$/ba};s/\(9[0-9]\{4\}\)\(\n\s*\)*[^\n]*9[0-9]\{4\}/\1/' file
```

This handles blank lines between consecutive similar lines.

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(9[0-9]\{4\}\)\(\n\s*\)*[^\n]*9[0-9]\{4\}/\1/;ta' file
```

As does this as well as multilple consecutive *similar* lines but slurps the whole file into pattern space.

Comment: This ones a tough one to decipher but i'll give it a shot.